# Error in C program using Fedora

Tags: c, gcc, queue, fedora

I get the following error when dealing with C using Fedora:

```
[king@localhost ~]$ gcc -o1 tempdaa.c
tempdaa.c:3:17: fatal error: queue: No such file or directory
#include <queue>
         ^
compilation terminated.
```

Any ideas on where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` is generally what you use to compile *C* code. If you want to compile *C++* code, you'd tend to use `g++`.

Now it's true that `gcc` can compile C++ if it's clear you *have* a C++ program but I think, from memory, that's indicated by the extension rather than the content.

Since your extension is `.c` rather than something like `.cpp` or `.cc` or `.cxx`, it will definitely think it's C code and behave accordingly.

Hence the C++ header `queue` will not be available to you.

My suggestion is that you name your C++ source files "correctly", or force the language type explicitly:

```
gcc -x c++ -o1 tempdaa.c
```